# Select first n items of dataframe based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to select first 3 items of column in a data frame based on another column like below

| Gene | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| G1 | 0 |
| G2 | 0 |
| G3 | 0 |
| G4 | 0 |
| G5 | 1 |
| G6 | 1 |
| G7 | 1 |
| G8 | 2 |
| G9 | 2 |
| G10 | 2 |

And the desired output would be :

| Cluster0 | Cluster1 | Cluster2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | G5 | G8 |
| G2 | G6 | G9 |
| G3 | G7 | G10 |

Comment: use `group_by` and `slice_head` and then `pivot_wider` as needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split then get first 3 items:

```
sapply(split(df$Gene, df$Cluster), head, 3)
#      0    1    2    
# [1,] "G1" "G5" "G8" 
# [2,] "G2" "G6" "G9" 
# [3,] "G3" "G7" "G10"
```

Pretty version, to get output as dataframe with proper column names:

```
data.frame(
  lapply(setNames(split(df$Gene, df$Cluster),
                  paste0("Cluster", unique(df$Cluster))), head, 3))

#   Cluster0 Cluster1 Cluster2
# 1       G1       G5       G8
# 2       G2       G6       G9
# 3       G3       G7      G10
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `tidyverse`

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'Gene   Cluster
G1  0
G2  0
G3  0
G4  0
G5  1
G6  1
G7  1
G8  2
G9  2
G10 2
G11 2
G12 2')

library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(Cluster) %>%
  slice_head(n = 3) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', values_from = Gene, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Cluster0 Cluster1 Cluster2
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 G1       G5       G8      
#> 2 G2       G6       G9      
#> 3 G3       G7       G10
```

---

2. OR in `tidyr` only

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', values_from = Gene, values_fn =\(x) list(head(x, 3))) %>%
  unnest(everything())

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Cluster0 Cluster1 Cluster2
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 G1       G5       G8      
#> 2 G2       G6       G9      
#> 3 G3       G7       G10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarking with 100K rows:

```
#bigger data
df <- data.frame(Gene = sample(LETTERS, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                 Cluster = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE))

library(tidyverse)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  x1 = {
    sapply(split(df$Gene, df$Cluster), head, 3)
  },
  x1.1 = {
    data.frame(
      lapply(setNames(split(df$Gene, df$Cluster),
                      paste0("Cluster", unique(df$Cluster))), head, 3))
  },
  x2 = {
    df %>% group_by(Cluster) %>%
      slice_head(n = 3) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', values_from = Gene, values_fn = list) %>%
      unnest(everything())
  },
  x3 = {
    df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', 
                       values_from = Gene, values_fn = function(x) list(head(x, 3))) %>%
      unnest(everything())
  },
  x4 = {
    df %>% group_by(Cluster) %>%
      slice_head(n = 3) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', values_from = Gene, values_fn = list) %>%
      unnest(everything())
    
  },
  x5 = {
    dcast(dt[, .SD[1:3], Cluster], rowid(Cluster) ~ Cluster, value.var = "Gene")
  }, unit = "relative"
)
```

The result:

```
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
   x1  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100 a   
 x1.1  2.694717  2.675554  2.787942  2.665159  2.835791  3.800284   100  b  
   x2 15.508268 15.426045 14.345951 15.478955 16.623557  6.122571   100    d
   x3 14.287112 14.009078 13.044710 14.146175 14.580066  5.267667   100   c 
   x4 15.490364 15.318374 14.640672 15.291183 16.025033 19.273504   100    d
   x5  3.758916  3.777874  3.554927  3.816470  3.864071  1.704555   100  b
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(Cluster) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:3) %>% 
    mutate(Cluster = Cluster + 1) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Cluster, names_prefix = 'Cluster', values_from = Gene) %>% 
        unnest(everything())
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Cluster1 Cluster2 Cluster3
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 G1       G5       G8      
2 G2       G6       G9      
3 G3       G7       G10
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dcast(dt[, .SD[1:3], Cluster], rowid(Cluster) ~ Cluster, value.var = "Gene")
```

which gives:

```
   Cluster  0  1   2
1:       1 G1 G5  G8
2:       2 G2 G6  G9
3:       3 G3 G7 G10
```

See also the updated benchmark post about the performance.